# angular bootstrap btn-radio does not change value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
 <label class="btn btn-sm btn-info"    ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'title'"><i class="fa fa-check text-active"></i> Jobprofil</label>
 <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'division'"><i class="fa fa-check text-active"></i> Afdelinger</label>
```

For this i have the following `$scope` variable:

```
$scope.radioModel = 'title';
```

And a listner for changes:

```
    $scope.$watch('radioModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue == 'title'){
        $scope.dataset = $scope.titleSet;
    }
    else if(newValue == 'division'){
        $scope.dataset = $scope.divisionDataset;
    }
}, true);
```

However whenever i click either of the  elements the value does not change (or atleast the `$watch` is not being called)

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything is OK in your snippet, `$watcher` is working fine, check the plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/c4bwHh8acsQZ2Y7RxCU9?p=preview